# How to customize Product page in magento?

Tags: magento

I want to change divs in magneto product description page Please help me how to do this

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell from which file this `div` is rendering. normally product description is in the file `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml`, if you are using default theme. But according to the screenshot you are using your own theme or any purchase theme. So it might be at different location.

Check the screenshot
[image]

Comment: @renusood :  if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.